# Sharekit Twitter Integration Broke in iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, sharekit

In previous iOS versions, using the Twitter functionality (with bit.ly)  Works perfect.  However, when I click submit to twitter, it posts, but doesn't remove the dialog.  It sounds similar to this bug (in fact the cancel button doesn't work either):

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/254

I tried the solution listed, but it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer on the actual bug

"Now that the NDA is lifted, I just changed the two instances of [[currentView parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] in SHK.m to [currentView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES].

This gist is my SHK.m: https://gist.github.com/1281191"

Comment: `if ([currentView parentViewController] != nil)` also has to change to `if (currentView != nil)` like in itruf's answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've changed code in function hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated and it works perfect.

My code:

```
- (void)hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (isDismissingView)
        return;

    if (currentView != nil)
    {
        self.isDismissingView = YES;
        [currentView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        NSLog(@"dismiss");
    }
}
```